# Story of Godess Saraswati?

Tags: scripture, saraswati

Why is She called

1. Vidyadatri (Goddess who provides knowledge)
2. Vagdevi (Goddess of speech)
3. Veenapani (Goddess carrying veena in her hands)
4. Hansavahini (Goddess who sits on swan)

Is there any story Which includes someone praying to Godess Saraswati, Godess Saraswati gives knowledge/wisdom **(Vidyadatri)**, removes his ignorance, correcting nonsensical speech **(Vagdevi)** gives a weapon/tool so that he can gain more knowledge (Giving Veena or Book) , What is the significance of veena **(Veenapani)**, swan or peacock **(Hansavahini)**.

Comment: I want to read Story of Godess Saraswati which shows the characteristics of Godess Saraswati.

Comment: Please refer this wiki. https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Saraswati

Comment: @SantoshAryal Have read that. It doesn't give any stories.

Comment: Read the following link to know why she is called Vagdevi. https://hinduism.stackexchange.com/questions/45864/who-is-goddess-sarasvatī-how-the-goddess-of-river-transformed-into-the-goddess